# Show modal on form validation success

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2, bootstrap-modal, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to launch a modal if my flask-wtf form validation fails. The code snippet below otherwise works as expected other than it launches the modal even when I load the form before submission (appears that form.errors initialises to False before form is submitted).

What do I need to change get the modal to show iff form is submitted and form validation is successful?

```
<script>
var formSuccess = {% if form.errors %}false{% else %}true{% endif %};

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (formSuccess) {
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by passing a validation_success variable when checking 
if form.validate_on_submit() within the calling routine. I then pick this value up using jija:

```
<script>
var formSuccess = {% if validation_success %}true{% else %}false{% endif %};

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (formSuccess) {
        $('.modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
    }
});
</script>
```